# How to get Enter Key action to call a PCL defined property from WPF using MVVM Cross

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, portable-class-library

My issue is that I wish to press enter after typing a text in a textbox. When I do, I want this to trigger a specific property in my viewmodel which is defined in my PCL *(this can not be changed)*.

I have seen some examples that almost do the similar thing but they only do standard actions such as clear text in textbox or tab to next control and so on. I want this one to interact with a property of my choice.

HeaderView.xaml

```
<views:MvxWpfView
         xmlns:views="clr-namespace:Cirrious.MvvmCross.Wpf.Views;assembly=Cirrious.MvvmCross.Wpf"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:UI="clr-namespace:ProductCatalog.UserInterface.WPF.Bootstrap"
         x:Class="ProductCatalog.UserInterface.WPF.Views.HeaderView">
<Grid Height="70" Background="#005287">
        <TextBox DataContext="{Binding SearchText}" UI:TextBoxExtension.EnterKey="Search" 
                 Width="120" Height="35" Padding="8" Margin="10" HorizontalAlignment="Right" >
        </TextBox>
</Grid></views:MvxWpfView>
```

HeaderView.xaml.cs

```
public partial class HeaderView : MvxWpfView
{
    public new HeaderViewModel ViewModel
    {
        get { return (HeaderViewModel) base.ViewModel; }
        set { base.ViewModel = value; }
    }

    public HeaderView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

HeaderViewModel.cs (In PCL)

```
public class HeaderViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
    private string _searchText;
    public string SearchText
    {
        get { return _searchText; }
        set
        {
            _searchText = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => SearchText);
        }
    }

    public ICommand Search
    {
        get
        {
            return new MvxCommand(() =>
            {
                SearchItems = new List<string> { "Hey", "Hello", "Hola" };
            });
        }
    }

    private IList<string> _searchItems;
    public IList<string> SearchItems
    {
        get { return _searchItems; }
        set { _searchItems = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => SearchItems); }
    }
}
```

TextBoxExtension.cs

```
public static class TextBoxExtension
{
    public static ICommand GetEnterKey(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (ICommand)obj.GetValue(EnterKey);
    }

    public static void SetEnterKey(DependencyObject obj, ICommand value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(EnterKey, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty EnterKey = 
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("EnterKey", typeof(ICommand), typeof(TextBoxExtension), new UIPropertyMetadata(EnterKeyPropertyChanged));

    static void EnterKeyPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        UIElement element = d as UIElement;
        if (element == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        element.KeyDown += Keydown;
    }

    static void Keydown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!e.Key.Equals(Key.Enter))
        {
            return;
        }

        UIElement element = sender as UIElement;
        if (element != null)
        {
            ICommand command = GetEnterKey(element);
            command.Execute(null);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is what happens, when I use the parameter `Search` into my UI:TextBoxEntension.EnterKey the event is triggered like I want it to, but it can't find my Search property in my ViewModel. When I try using `{Binding Search}` then the event is never triggered. How can I get the event to trigger my Search property in my ViewModel.

Many thanks

Comment: My apologies for diverting you to the more complicated solution. I was taking as granted that your use of `KeyBinding` had been done correctly, and that that truly was not an option for you; I should have double-checked that myself...had I done so, I would have found that `KeyBinding` works fine as you want it to, and insisted on a good [mcve] showing your problem rather than looking for alternatives to `KeyBinding` for you.

Comment: Which is to say: I have written a [mcve] myself that does nothing but declare a `KeyBinding` on a `TextBox` to execute a command when `Enter` is pressed, and it works fine. I would post it here as an answer, except that seeing it done correctly isn't going to help you figure out why in your code doing the same thing in XAML doesn't have the same result. Please improve your question, making sure it includes a good code example that reliably reproduces the problem.

Comment: Can you provide an example where the `KeyBinding` with `Enter` key as command really works, I have done several tests of this on a clean solution and can never get it to work. What am I doing wrong? @PeterDuniho

Comment: @PeterDuniho I have now found out the solution to my problem. Apparently there was a binding that implemented this functionality that was incorrectly set.
Which rendered the entire question mute, since it was working.
Since you seem to be knowledgeble in the stackoverflow community, how do I report this, do I remove the question? I still wanna thank everyone involved in helping me out

Comment: I'm glad you figured it out. Good job! As for the question, the primary question you need to ask yourself is: "will my question and its answer(s) help someone in the future?" I.e. is it likely that someone might have the same question, and find in your presentation and at least one of the answers the _solution_ to their problem. Given that this seems to have turned out to be essentially a typo in your code, the answer to that analysis is likely "not". You may vote to close your own question (use the "off-topic/typographical error" reason, or delete it outright.

Comment: The reason for voting to close instead of deleting it outright would be that if you do, then it will still be possible for _any_ user (not just those with enough reputation to see deleted posts) to read comments you may leave for them, such as a brief thanks for their input if you really want to.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using InputBindings:

```
<TextBox>
    <TextBox.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Key="Enter" Command="{Binding DoSomething}"/>
    </TextBox.InputBindings>
</TextBox>
```

And in your ViewModel:

```
DoSomething = new RelayCommand(() => DoSomething(), () => true);
```

Comment: I have tried InputBindings, however this never executes when an the enter key is pressed.

Comment: Hmm, I don't see why it shouldn't. Finding out why it doesn't execute will lead you to the solution to the problem.

Comment: But you have tried using the `KeyBinding` before for a textbox and succeeded? Since I'm new to WPF it might very well be something entirly different I have missed

Comment: I can confirm that it does work, I'm using it in my current project. I'm using MVVM Light though

Comment: I can't even get it to work in a new WPF project without anything in it except a textbox in `MainWindow.xaml` and the property in `MainWindow.xaml.cs`. I just don't get this

Comment: Have you bound your view to your view model correctly? Does anything 'binding' related work for this view?

Comment: Nope, doesn't seem like it does in this usercontrol. But in all others it do and they are basically identical.

Comment: The DataContext needs to be set in your view. This can be done in your xaml or in the code behind your view (MVVM design pattern recommends you do it in the xaml). Check your other views to see how they are bound.

Answer (score 0):

First,  you should define your Attached property as

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty EnterKeyProperty = 
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("EnterKey", typeof(ICommand), typeof(TextBoxExtension), new UIPropertyMetadata(EnterKeyPropertyChanged));


public static ICommand GetEnterKey(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (ICommand)obj.GetValue(EnterKeyProperty);
    }

    public static void SetEnterKey(DependencyObject obj, ICommand value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(EnterKeyProperty, value);
    }
```

This is to differentiate between attached property and CLR property.

Second binding should happen as

```
 <TextBox DataContext="{Binding SearchText}" UI:TextBoxExtension.EnterKey="{Binding Search}" 
                 Width="120" Height="35" Padding="8" Margin="10" HorizontalAlignment="Right" >
        </TextBox>
```

Comment: Like I have stated in my question. When I do write `{Binding Search}` instead of `Search` as a parameter to EnterKey the Keydown will not be called.
It will only say `A binding cannot be usedwithin a textbox collection. Abinding can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject`

Comment: Are you getting any binding failure in output window?

Comment: No, I can't find anything that refers to binding failiure. However I can't see that it binds either so I am assuming it doesn't for some reason.